# nginx substitude file sitemap.xml on subdomain

Tags: nginx, sitemap

I have file sitemap.xml in site public directory. When I use subdomain 'm.', it uses same public directory as general site. I need to return file '/mobile-sitemap.xml' from url '/sitemap.xml', when I'm on subdomain 'm.'.

What nginx modules and rules could help me to do this?

My first step was like this:

`if ($host ~* m\.(.*)) {
    #if url = /sitemap.xml, give back file /mobile-sitemap.xml as /sitemap.xml
}`

Or maybe it's ok to google, if i just send 301 redirect to another sitemap file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate server block for your mobile subdomain, in which case the `if` statement would not be necessary. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

However, to implement this in a single server block, use a `location` and a `rewrite`:

```
location = /sitemap.xml {
    if ($host ~* m\.) {
        rewrite ^ /mobile-sitemap.xml last;
    }
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.